# How to drop specific packet captured in NS-3 mesh node?

Tags: wifi, packet, ns-3, mesh-network, drop

I'm using NS-3 v3.28.1 to simulation a WiFi Mesh network. The grid topology (actually only one line, with IEEE 802.11s stack installed at each node, HWMP protocol) contains 3 WiFi Mesh nodes, ***Node0***, ***Node1*** and ***Node2***. Then I bind a UDP socket (acting as ***receiver***) in ***Node0***, and another (acting as ***sender***) in ***Node2***. ***Node2*** send a UDP packet to ***Node0*** through ***Node1*** every 10ms. The topology as follow:

***Node0*** (***receiver***)   <---  ***Node1***  <----   ***Node2*** (***sender***)

***10.1.1.1/24***                               ***10.1.1.2/24***              ***10.1.1.3/24***

Then I set a MonitorSnifferRx function on ***Node1*** to listen udp packets sent from ***Node2*** to ***Node0*** using `Config::ConnectWithoutContext`:

```
Config::ConnectWithoutContext ("/NodeList/1/DeviceList/*/Phy/MonitorSnifferRx", MakeCallback (&DecodeRxPktCB));
```

In ***Node1*** callback function DecodeRxPktCB, I can decode the udp packet sent from ***Node2*** to ***Node0***.

**My question is** :
when a specific UDP packet captured (with content match some rules) in ***Node1***'s MonitorSnifferRx callback function, how can I drop it thus it will not transfer to ***Node0***?  I see that the first parameter in MonitorSnifferRx callback function is "Ptr< **const** Packet > packet", with const value only can read.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [NS-3 Packet](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/classns3_1_1_packet.html) class to grab the information you need and filter it.

If you can, I'd recommend adding a packet tag (or ByteTag) on the sender, making it easier for your middle node to filter it. Packet tag details are also on the link above.